# Why runtime error for 2 out of 8 cases?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, runtime-error

I've completed [Hackerrank's "Birthday Cake Candles" challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/rookierank/challenges/birthday-cake-candles) and have passed 6 out of 8 test cases using the following code that sorts an array, then increments the frequency that the max int occurs and prints that value:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numCandles = in.nextInt();
        int height[] = new int[numCandles];
        for(int height_i=0; height_i < numCandles; height_i++){
            height[height_i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        //Option 2: Sort the array, then count the number that are highest.
        Arrays.sort(height);
        int max = height[height.length - 1];
        int index = height.length - 1;
        int freq = 0;
        while(height[index] == max) {
            freq++;
            index--;
        }
        System.out.println(freq);
    }
}
```

It's not passing Test Case #6 ([input](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/23074/input06.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1486675348&Signature=RDza79kLYKg%2FYtsZTGJSZRQlSdQ%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)) or Test Case #7. In short, Test Case #6 is 100,000 occurrences of the int 999999 and Test Case #7 is 100,000 occurrences of the int 1. Expected output for both is supposed to be 100000.

I'm thinking it might be encountering a runtime error because of the sorting method I call on the array and the array trying to sort ints of equal value over and over? Can anyone explain why my code won't work for those two Test Cases?

Comment: Arrr, what happens when **you** run this code?

Comment: you should close your input scanner

Comment: check that in `while-loop` when index goes to less than zero.

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see what happens. That approch works in >90% of the cases

Comment: this way is not efficient , in worst case has `O(n^2)` , there is a better way in `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

When all values in the input are the same, as in the sample input you included, the condition in this loop will be `true` until `index` is reduced to -1, at which point you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

> ```
> while(height[index] == max) {
>     freq++;
>     index--;
> }
> ```

Add a range check to the loop condition, for example:

```
while (index >= 0 && height[index] == max) {
```

With this change, the solution will pass all tests. But it's an inefficient solution. You sorted the input to reduce the number of iterations in the `while` loop. But sorting is an `O(n log(n))` operation, which is slower than a simple filtering with `O(n)`. For example:

```
int numCandles = in.nextInt();
int heights[] = new int[numCandles];
int m = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < numCandles; i++) {
    heights[i] = in.nextInt();
    m = Math.max(m, heights[i]);
}

final int max = m;
long freq = IntStream.of(heights).filter(x -> x == max).count();
System.out.println(freq);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an outbound of exception because you are reaching a part when you go less than 0

```
while(height[index] == max) {

    freq++;
                if(index == 0)
        break;
    index--;
}
```

This is my solution for this problem

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int height[] = new int[n];
        for(int height_i=0; height_i < n; height_i++){
            height[height_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(height);
        int counter = 0;
        int different = height[n-1];
       for(int height_i=n-1; height_i >=0 ; height_i--){

           if(different ==height[height_i] )
            {
            counter = counter  + 1;   


           }
           else 
               {
               break;
           }

        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
```

This is my solution for this. I think is better to use a for than a while for this.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question. It's an independent implementation.

Comment: My bad you are right. I go directly and did the problem by myself now edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Solution

```
static int birthdayCakeCandles(int[] arr) {
          int max = arr[0];
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<arr.length;i++) {

        if(max < arr[i]) {

            max = arr[i];
        }

    }
    for(int i =0; i<arr.length;i++) {

        if(max == arr[i]) {

            count++;
        }

    }
 return count;
}
```